# Octopus deploy - Substitute variable with .json content

Tags: octopus-deploy

I have a .sql file that contains a json variable. I want to put this json in a separate .json file and substitute in .sql file the variable from .json when i deploy with octopus. Is any way to do this substitution in octopus? variable substitute with .json content. I don't know if i was clear.

Comment: `I don't know if i was clear.` < it is not, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In your .sql file, replace the value with `#{variableName}`. See: [Binding Syntax](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/variables/binding-syntax) AND [Variables](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/variables).
In your project in Octopus, declare a variable with the same name `#{variableName}` and enter your JSON in the value field.

Read about [Substitute Variables in Files](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/substitute-variables-in-files), and make sure you state the name of the file you want substitution to occur on. For example: `mySqlFile.sql`, or just `*.sql`. Pay special attention to the requirement:

> You need to state the full path of the file, relative to the installation directory. So, if you need to replace variables on a file called app.config that is inside of a configfolder on the root of your package, you need to put config\app.configon the Target files field.